# Which material should be used for incense?

Tags: scripture, rituals

Hindus generally use different types of sticks for incense.

The health of individuals living in a home [may be affected](https://www.healthline.com/health/is-incense-bad-for-you) by the content of incense used during prayer.

Is there any scriptural recommendation for materials to be used for incense?

Comment: Those who voted for closing: Many hindu families perform pooja in home for 3 times and incense is a part of it,